# How can i fix "error CS0009: Metadata file "System.Xml.dll' could not be opened -- Image is too small"?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a new windows desktop application in visual studio, and I haven't changed the application at all since two days ago at which time it built just fine, however when I try to build the application again it gives the following error.

CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll' could not be opened -- Image is too small.

Comment: @Haldo - How can either of those be duplicates? They have distinctly different error messages from what OP posted.

Comment: I too am seeing the same thing in a .net core 2.2 project, I suspect mine is related to earlier experiments copying dll's around attempting IoC n-tier isolation. For me it only happens on the build server and works fine locally. I also see an earlier warning stating I have a duplicate dll reference that can't be resolved. This may not help you, but might give you an idea of where to look next. If I find the solution I'll share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to build by deleting the **System.Xml.dll** file. IF anyone is gonna attempt to do this you should to back up the file.

I'm not sure this is a solution or if "The bill comes due".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with this problem, you can resolve it with a simple clean/build sln. Do NOT rebuild it, only the clean and then build in sln will make it works.